# Ansible playbook to fetch JSON file from an API via 'uri'

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I wrote an Ansible playbook intend to fetch the list from an API as JSON file using `uri` module as below.

```yaml
- name: API check
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name : "Get the list as JSON"
    uri:
     url: http://sampleapitest.com/api
     user: test
     password: test
     force_basic_auth: yes
     status_code: 200
     body_format: json
     dest: "/home/peterw/list.json"
```

But when I am running the Playbook it is showing that the Playbook needs Hosts file. But I have access only to the URL, not to the SSH port 22.

```
ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set
```

I am new to Ansible. Can anyone please help me to fetch the details from the API as JSON file?

Comment: add hosts: localhost

Comment: other ways exist see my answer

Answer (score 1):

you have lot of ways to resolve your problem

either you have hosts defined, and you want to use an ansible module only on localhost, so you add `delegate_to: localhost`  and `run_once: true`  to signify i just want to play this task only one time.

```
- hosts:  listohhosts
  tasks:
    - name: what does the task
      moduleusing:
        param1:
         :
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

either you add `hosts: localhost`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write tasks like

```yaml
  - name: Gather stored entitlement from repository service
    local_action:
      module: uri
      url: "https://{{ REPOSITORY_URL }}/api/system/security/certificates"
      method: GET
      url_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      url_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
      validate_certs: yes
      return_content: yes
      status_code: 200
      body_format: json
    check_mode: false
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.json }}"
    check_mode: false
```

which in example gather installed certificates from a JFrog Artifactory repository service via REST API call, as well

```yaml
  - name: Gather stored entitlement from repository service
    action:
      module: uri
      ...
```

> `local_action`
> Same as action but also implies `delegate_to: localhost`

for [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html).